# Combining INNER JOIN and JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join

I'm looking to join multiple tables into one report and need help with my "INNER JOIN" and "JOIN" approach. I'm looking for a result similar to using the "UNION" call but I would like the results from each table to display in separate columns rather than all in one column. Here are the 3 queries I would like to join into one report with (ideally) 4 distinct columns (Job Title, Skills, Abilities, Work Activities)

```
SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], Abilities.Ability
FROM (Departments INNER JOIN [Job Titles] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Job Titles].[Department]) INNER JOIN (Abilities INNER JOIN [Department/Ability] ON Abilities.AbilityID = [Department/Ability].Ability) ON (Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Ability].Department) AND (Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Ability].Department)
WHERE ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"));

SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], Skills.Skill
FROM Skills INNER JOIN ((Departments INNER JOIN [Job Titles] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Job Titles].[Department]) INNER JOIN [Department/Skills] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Skills].Department) ON Skills.SkillID = [Department/Skills].Skills
WHERE ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"));

SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], [Work Activities].[Work Activities]
FROM Employees INNER JOIN ([Work Activities] INNER JOIN (([Job Titles] INNER JOIN [Employee/JobTitle] ON [Job Titles].JobTitleID = [Employee/JobTitle].[Job Title]) INNER JOIN [JobTitles/WorkActivities] ON [Job Titles].JobTitleID = [JobTitles/WorkActivities].[Job Title]) ON [Work Activities].[Work ActivitiesID] = [JobTitles/WorkActivities].[Work Activity]) ON Employees.WorkerID = [Employee/JobTitle].Employee
GROUP BY [Job Titles].[Job Title], [Work Activities].[Work Activities]
HAVING ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"));
```

Here are photos of the three tables I'll like to combine into one report/query.

[image: Work Activities]
[image: Skills]
[image: Abilities]
[image: Ideal Output]

Anyone can help? I'm learning SQL on my own and cannot figure this one out. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Please read [Question Check](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) list and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Are you sure you are working with sql server? That mess of parenthesis looks like the kind of crazy that only Access throws together. Also, your string literals here are in double quotes which is not what sql server uses.

Comment: JOIN means INNER JOIN. Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: You are not explaining what you want. If you did, you could search & find that is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this will give you the exact results you want, but the syntax is similar to how I tackle your stated scenario.

```sql
SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], Null As Skill, Abilities.Ability, Null As [Work Activities]
FROM (Departments INNER JOIN [Job Titles] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Job Titles].[Department]) INNER JOIN (Abilities INNER JOIN [Department/Ability] ON Abilities.AbilityID = [Department/Ability].Ability) ON (Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Ability].Department) AND (Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Ability].Department)
WHERE ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"))
UNION
SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], Skills.Skill, Null Null
FROM Skills INNER JOIN ((Departments INNER JOIN [Job Titles] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Job Titles].[Department]) INNER JOIN [Department/Skills] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Skills].Department) ON Skills.SkillID = [Department/Skills].Skills
WHERE ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"))
UNION
SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], Null, Null, [Work Activities].[Work Activities]
FROM Employees INNER JOIN ([Work Activities] INNER JOIN (([Job Titles] INNER JOIN [Employee/JobTitle] ON [Job Titles].JobTitleID = [Employee/JobTitle].[Job Title]) INNER JOIN [JobTitles/WorkActivities] ON [Job Titles].JobTitleID = [JobTitles/WorkActivities].[Job Title]) ON [Work Activities].[Work ActivitiesID] = [JobTitles/WorkActivities].[Work Activity]) ON Employees.WorkerID = [Employee/JobTitle].Employee
GROUP BY [Job Titles].[Job Title], [Work Activities].[Work Activities]
HAVING ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"));
```

Comment: Raymond, this definitely gets me closer to the output I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help/code.

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome. Glad to assist. Well, if my previous reply was on target, maybe this will provide what you want...

```sql
SELECT j As [Job Title], MAX(s) As Skill, MAX(a) As Ability, MAX(wa) As [Work Activities]
FROM
(SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title] As j, Null As s, Abilities.Ability As a, Null As wa
FROM (Departments INNER JOIN [Job Titles] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Job Titles].[Department]) INNER JOIN (Abilities INNER JOIN [Department/Ability] ON Abilities.AbilityID = [Department/Ability].Ability) ON (Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Ability].Department) AND (Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Ability].Department)
WHERE ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"))
UNION
SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], Skills.Skill, Null Null
FROM Skills INNER JOIN ((Departments INNER JOIN [Job Titles] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Job Titles].[Department]) INNER JOIN [Department/Skills] ON Departments.DepartmentID = [Department/Skills].Department) ON Skills.SkillID = [Department/Skills].Skills
WHERE ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President"))
UNION
SELECT [Job Titles].[Job Title], Null, Null, [Work Activities].[Work Activities]
FROM Employees INNER JOIN ([Work Activities] INNER JOIN (([Job Titles] INNER JOIN [Employee/JobTitle] ON [Job Titles].JobTitleID = [Employee/JobTitle].[Job Title]) INNER JOIN [JobTitles/WorkActivities] ON [Job Titles].JobTitleID = [JobTitles/WorkActivities].[Job Title]) ON [Work Activities].[Work ActivitiesID] = [JobTitles/WorkActivities].[Work Activity]) ON Employees.WorkerID = [Employee/JobTitle].Employee
GROUP BY [Job Titles].[Job Title], [Work Activities].[Work Activities]
HAVING ((([Job Titles].[Job Title])="President")))
GROUP BY j;
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to adjust/hide the empty cells so when a report is called, all of my shows up on 25 rows as opposed to 51? The most recent code you offered captures the general format I'm looking for but only one row emerged Capturing all 4 categories

Comment: Apologies for all of the questions. I'm new at this.

Comment: No problem. We were all new once. After I posted the latest code I realized that it would only return 1 row because you are filtering for 1 specific job title (president). Does your data involve multiple employees who have that specific job title?

Comment: Thank you for understanding. In my Access database, there are multiple employees with the same job title but not for the "President" job title (the one I used in the example).